# How are military aircraft numbered?

Tags: military, aircraft-naming

Can someone describe the numbering system used by the military and how it has changed over the years?  I know that there are fighter aircraft such as the F-15, F-16, F-22, etc but why are there aircraft numbered like the F-117?  and why is the B-2 a B-2 when we have had B-17s in the past?

Comment: Surely you mean only in the American army?

Comment: Related: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20899/why-isnt-the-f15e-called-f-a15  and http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/20920/was-the-intended-purpose-of-the-f-117-nighthawk-originally-a-stealth-fighter?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Antzi None of those aircraft are flown by the American Army.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At present, all US military aircraft follow the [1962 United States Tri-Service aircraft designation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_United_States_Tri-Service_aircraft_designation_system). The first letter ('F' or 'B') denotes the mission of the aircraft, while the number denotes the design number. The designation system produces a Mission-Design-Series (MDS) designation. From [Designating and Naming Military Aerospace Vehicles](http://static.e-publishing.af.mil/production/1/af_a8/publication/afi16-401/afi16-401.pdf):

> 4.1. Designator Definition:
>
> 4.1.1.The  MDS designator is an official DoD recognized alpha-numeric symbol designation of a military defense aerospace vehicle. .... The designator describes the aerospace vehicle in two components where the components are separated by a hash.The first component, comprised  only  of  alpha characters, describes the mission of the vehicle.The second component, comprised of both alpha-numeric characters, describes the design number and design series of the vehicle.
>
> 4.1.2. Standard  aircraft MDS designators are comprised of the following: status prefix(optional), modified mission(optional), basic mission(required), design number (required), design series (required).

The document also gives some examples of this implemenatation:

[image: Tri Service designation]

[image: Tri service designation- examples]

Both tables from [Designating and Naming Military Aerospace Vehicles](http://static.e-publishing.af.mil/production/1/af_a8/publication/afi16-401/afi16-401.pdf)

The 1962 system replaced the earlier system, where each service had their own systems in place for naming of aircraft.

- From 1924 - 1962, the USAF (and the [USAAF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Army_Air_Forces) before them) used the [1924 United States Army Air Service aircraft designation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1924_United_States_Army_Air_Service_aircraft_designation_system).
- During the same time, the USN used the [1922 United States Navy aircraft designation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1922_United_States_Navy_aircraft_designation_system).
- Once the USAF was formed from the USAAF in 1947, the US Army followed the [1956 United States Army aircraft designation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1956_United_States_Army_aircraft_designation_system) till 1962.
- Before all of these was the [1919 United States Army Air Service aircraft designation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1919_United_States_Army_Air_Service_aircraft_designation_system).

More details about the aircraft designation can be found in [this page](http://www.personal.psu.edu/users/d/o/dob104/aviation/us/system.html#tri).

Basically, the counters were reset while the 1962 sytem was adopted, leading to unrelated sets of aircraft numbering. As for individual aircraft numbering, there has been a number of cases where the system was not followed, like the [F-117 Nighthawk](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/20931/9731).

Adherence to this system has been patchy at best. So, you have [B-1 Lancer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockwell_B-1_Lancer) and [B-2 Spirit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_B-2_Spirit) *after* [B-52 Stratofortress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_B-52_Stratofortress) (this was due to the counters being reset), while the next bomber has been named [B-21 Raider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northrop_Grumman_B-21_Raider).

Comment: And what are the usual missions of the vehicle that gives the first component, comprised only of alpha characters? F for fighter? B for Bomber? W for weather?

Comment: @Marine1 Yes. A for  attack, B for Bomber, C for transport etc. It's in attachment 3 of the linked document.