# What does the letter E signify for the E-3 AWACS?

Tags: military, aircraft-naming

I came across the E-3 AWACS aircraft with the designation E-3, I could not find what the letter E means in E-3.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32217/62)

Answer (score 20):

The E isn't exactly the short form of a word as it is a mission designation. In the US military's Tri-Service aircraft designation system, E indicates that the aircraft performs special electronic missions. Similarly, F implies the aircraft is a fighter aircraft and B indicates the aircraft performs bombing missions.

edit: here is the [US military aircraft designation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1962_United_States_Tri-Service_aircraft_designation_system)

Comment: Sounds like E is the short form of "electronic" 

Comment: @Josef yes, but they aren't all that way.  L is cold weather, K is tanker, etc.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: I thought K for tankers came from "K"erosene (jet fuel)?

Comment: @Sean or just tanKer (like coLd weather).  The US military has a long history of it, though.  e.g. carriers being CV comes from them being a cruiser hull (C) using heavier than air aircraft (V).

Comment: @MarshallTigerus: And here I thought CV was an abbreviation for "(aircraft-) "C"arrier "V"essel".  Guess I learnt something new today!